# Fade through a sequence of divs — jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

The code thus far fades through a sequence of `<li>` items. `The next_arrow` appends the latest div to the bottom of the list, giving the illusion that is at the front of the slide show.

However, when I try to mirror the code with the `left_arrow`, it breaks and fades out the `li` completely.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/7FA8h/42/)

```
 $('li:first-child').siblings().hide();


            $('.right_arrow').click(function () {
                $(this)
                    .parent('.container')
                    .find('li:first-child')
                    .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(200);
                    $(this).appendTo('ul');
                });
            });

          $('.left_arrow').click(function () {
                $(this)
                    .parent('.container')
                    .find('li:first-child')
                    .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $(this).prev().fadeIn(200);
                    $(this).appendTo('ul');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.. I have used a class to keep track of the active `li`. This will keep a track of the element when different buttons are clicked.

And instead of appending the `li` again , I am just referring to the correct li using the length property.

```
  $('li:first-child').siblings().hide();


  $('.right_arrow').click(function () {
      // Check for the active li..
      // If length is zero.. set the first one to active
      // caching the variables
      var $active = $('li.active'),
          $this = $(this),
          $container = $this.closest('.container');
     // If active length is 0 then set active as first li
      var $li = $active.length ? $active : $('li:first-child');

      $li.fadeOut(200, function () {
         // When fadeout you need to get the next element
         // if length of next is 0 then use first 
          var $curr = $li.next('li').length ? $li.next('li') : $('li:first-child');
          // Add class to active elem and remove for others
          $curr.fadeIn(200).addClass('active');
          $curr.siblings().removeClass('active');
      });
  });

  $('.left_arrow').click(function () {
       // Check for the active li..
      // If length is zero.. set the first one to active
      var $active = $('li.active'),
          $this = $(this),
          $container = $this.closest('.container');
      var $li = $active.length ? $active : $('li:last-child');

      $li.fadeOut(200, function () {
          var $curr = $li.prev('li').length ? $li.prev('li') : $('li:last-child');
          $curr.fadeIn(200).addClass('active');
          $curr.siblings().removeClass('active');
      });
  });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7FA8h/48/)**

Comment: That won't slide the previous `li` in, it will start all over again :(